# get into socket.io room and access to this room from all events

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a function that put me inside of a room but when I try to send call to the users in this room from other event I need to join again on each event calls. then I want to stay join on for all the events emitters.

example

```
socket.on('join_room',function(room){
   socket.join(room);
})

socket.on('do_something',function(room){
    socket.join(room);
    io.to(room).emit('something');
});
```

then I want to call `socket.on('join_room',function(room)` and stay in the room always to call `socket.on('do_something',function(room)` when I needed as

```
socket.on('do_something',function(room){
    io.to(room).emit('something');
});
```

on to simple event this is not needed but when have many of them it is useful

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking for- do you want to be able to join multiple rooms?

Comment: no, I just want to join in the room one time, and them send diferent messages with differents event without to join again each time when I want to send something

Comment: `.join()` will only be undone if the client closes its socket (e.g. loads a new page) or if your server does a `.leave()`.

Comment: then didnt work if i make a join in one page and go to other? even if I maintain the socket.userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A webSocket (or socket.io socket on top of a webSocket) exists only for the duration of one page.  When the user navigates to a new page, the existing webSocket is closed and then your new page is free to create a new one if it wants, but the prior webSocket is no longer available.  If you log the connect and disconnect events in your server, you will see a disconnect and then a connect each time the user navigates to a new page.

Thus, when you `.join()` one webSocket on one page, that has nothing to do with another webSocket created on another page.  That webSocket on the next page will be created from scratch again and your server will have to `.join()` it into whatever rooms you want it to be in.

> then didnt work if i make a join in one page and go to other? even if
>   I maintain the socket.userid

When the user goes to a new page, the socket from the prior page will be closed (thus losing any rooms it may be joined to) and your client code will have to create a new socket and thus your server will again have to put that new socket into the desired rooms.

Your client page initialization code should create the desired socket and then send any appropriate initialization messages to the server.  The server should see the newly socket connect and can then do any appropriate setup on that socket.

Comment: thank u!!!!! now I understand that thing, I change my `.join()` place to the actual page and works as I specked +1 for your answer